# Unable to create channel in Hyperledger fabric using custom crypto graphic material

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the below link to run the first network sample using the custom crypto graphic material.

[First Network with custom cryptographic material](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-build-blockchain-network-with-custom-cryptographic-material-from-your-certificate-authority/index.html)

Post generation of certificates from the Third Party CA. i have places all the certificates in the required dir structure. Following other steps now when i start the docker containers they come up. but when i try to create channell i get below error

`Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining`

when i check the docker logs for the orderer container i find

```
DEBU 29f Checking if identity satisfies ADMIN role for Org1MSP
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2a0 0xc420111280 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: **This identity is not an admin**
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2a1 0xc420111280 principal evaluation fails
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2a2 0xc420111280 gate 1510557696533528831 evaluation fails
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2a3 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2a4 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2a5 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Admins ==
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2a6 0xc420111290 gate 1510557696533664185 evaluation starts
2017-11-13 07:21:36.533 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2a7 0xc420111290 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
```

So I think identity might not be in the admin list,
but when I go and check the below paths i find they have same admin cert

/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.aexp.com/users/Admin@org1.aexp.com/msp/admincerts

and

```
crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.aexp.com/msp/admincerts
```

If i am supposed to make the identity as admin what steps do i need to follow.

Kindly suggest
TIA

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes it was resolved by copying the signer cert to the admin certs folder

Comment: I am facing the same issue can you please elaborate more about the solution, that will help me, thanks in advance....

Comment: Add the signer certificate to the admin folder. this should resolve your issue